# Why container based on ubuntu didn't run from docker-compose file, when that work for similar nginx container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to run docker container using docker-compose file instead of a long command line.

I want to run docker-compose file based on ubuntu:latest. Container created but can't run.

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    container_name: nginx_from_scratch3
    ports:
     - "80:80"
```

But before I've tried add in my docker-compose file line

```
command: bash
```

And noting change. I think what after running container continue to work. But that didn't happend.

But on the other side if I use nginx image all run perfectly.

```
version: "3.9"

services:

nginx1:
  image: nginx
  container_name: nginx_from_scratch4
  ports:
    - "80:80"
```

Why docker-compose file for nginx image work, and doesn’t work for ubuntu image.

Comment: `but can't run` - why not, what happens? Some errors?  What commands did you use to try to run/start?  Edit your question and add details.

Comment: I use windows and docker desktop. In docker desktop apeared new container. But for  ubuntu image is  a grey message "exited(0)".

Comment: Exit code 0 means "finished OK".

Comment: But before I've tried add in my docker-compose file line

**command: bash**
And noting change. I think what after running container continue to work. But that didn't happend. But if I add **command: tail -F anything** all work OK.
Why **command: bash** doesn't work?

Comment: A bare `ubuntu` container doesn't have any software installed and doesn't really do anything.  You probably want to build a custom image that includes your application and run that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker container exits if task inside is done. So when you run nginx, it starts nginx automatically and keep it alive. As for ubuntu, there's no any task to keep running and container ended immediately. So if you want to keep it alive even if it does not have any job: add tail -f, like this:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu
    command: tail -F anything
```

After you do docker container ps you will see it running.

And you can move to it with

```
docker exec -it container_name bash
```

Comment: I've tried it. I've added
**command: tail -F anything**

And that really work. 



But before I've tried add in my docker-compose file line
command: bash 

And noting change. I think what after running container it continue to work. But that didn't happend. 

Why **"command: bash"** doesn't work?